# Clang format don't break at first closing parens in function pointer

Tags: c, clang-format

`clang-format` formats a function pointer to this:

```c
uint32_t (*write
)(void*    ctx,
  uint8_t  tps_address,
  uint8_t  reg_address,
  uint8_t  byte_count,
  uint8_t* buffer);
```

Where I want it to look like this:

```c
uint32_t (*write)(
  void*    ctx,
  uint8_t  tps_address,
  uint8_t  reg_address,
  uint8_t  byte_count,
  uint8_t* buffer
  );
```

My [.clang-format](https://gist.github.com/jaskij/e2646cb88477d47d42ab5862dd677a31).

Which setting, if any, am I missing? Which would influence this?

As a bonus question, why would `clang-format` indent by two spaces here when I have this?

```yaml
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWidth: 4
```

Edit:

Thinking more about this, it seems more like a bug in Clang-Format than proper behavior, so I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58496).

Comment: Could you add rest of your `.clang-format` file.

Comment: Did you tried `TabWidth: 4` for indentation? And for other thing, it will work as expected in my system. Might be related with `ColumnLimit`.

Comment: @erenalyoruk `TabWidth: 4` didn't change a thing. Thinking about it now, the two spaces indent is probably a red herring here - I have it set so that arguments are aligned, and two spaces probably come from `)(` there.

Comment: Setting `AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak` fixed this issue. For indentation I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @erenalyoruk that helps, but breaks a different thing - the closing bracket isn't after a break :/ I consider this weirdness with function pointers the lesser of two evils if I have to choose. But it seems to me like `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent` is slightly borked in this case. Might open an issue on their tracker.